# react - Remove test only props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

In our code base, we use `data-automation-id` properties for both unit and end-to-end tests on react components that we want to have easy access to in these tests. For example:

```
<button data-automation-id="sign-up-button" />
```

While this is useful during dev and testing, I would like to strip this property off of any react component in production mode.

We are using babel6 to transpile the JSX and es2015 code and since that is where the JSX is converted into a series of react statements, I feel like this needs to be a babel plugin.

Does anyone have experience with something like this? Does such a tool already exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a babel plugin that can remove those attributes:

```
export default function ({types: t}) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      JSXAttribute(path) {
        if (path.node.name.name === "data-automation-id") {
          path.remove();
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```

http://astexplorer.net/#/o1vWnRkzqF